# Py2exe not connecting to internet (in particular, Github)?

Tags: python, github, py2exe

I recently created a script that connects to Github using the pygithub3 module for Python. It gets an inputted username's repos, counts the languages, and tells you their favorite repos. This works using IDLE, but once converted using py2exe, it no longer works and an error is thrown that it's not connecting to github. Woould anyone knows why this is?

I can post parts of the script if anyone needs it to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Could your firewall or anti-virus software be blocking access? Your script is now a standalone .exe file, whereas before it was something being interpreted by the `python.exe` application -- so your system may not trust it.

Comment: I tried running it with both Windows security and Windows firewall turned off, and it threw the same error, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It would help a great deal if you had a specific error message or type of error -- or better yet, a full traceback.

Comment: Annoyingly, the program py2exe creates just crashes when it hits the error, unless i specify an error message to be shown. It works just fine in IDLE, so there's no error message shown there either.

Comment: If you can specify an error message to be shown, it doesn't sound like it crashed...just that something failed. What is it?

Comment: Well if not crashing, it still closes itself immediately, and so has no time to tell me what failed.

Comment: The problem is identical using pyinstaller - this is very frustrating!